# Does Mobile IE 10 or 11 on Windows Phone still respect X-UA-Compatible?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-phone, x-ua-compatible

I'm curious if Mobile IE 10 or 11 on Windows Phone will still respect X-UA-Compatible, just like it does on desktop browsers.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8,chrome=1">
```

Could somebody please test this page from a Windows Phone in IE 10 or 11? http://calgary.ca/Scripts/ie8test.htm - I've added in the same X-UA-Compatible setting as it is written above and then display a javascript alert message if the page is being viewed in IE8 mode. Do you see the javascript alert saying that you're viewing in IE 8 mode?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just teste in my Nokia Lumia 920 running Windows Phone 8.1 Preview. It has show:

[image]
  [image]